# How to define map(list(string) and map(string) as a variable type in single variable block?

Tags: azure, terraform

**For azure cdn i'm excpecting to add rule engine/delivery rules ,so here in one of the block called  **request_scheme_condition** contains two arguments are **match_value** & **operator** here match_value is expecting list of strings and operator is expecting string only.**

```
variable "delivery_rules" {
   default = {
    name  = "test"
    order = 1
    request_scheme_condition = {
      match_value = ["HTTP"]

      operator = "Equal"
    }
  }

  type = object(
    {
      name                     = string
      order                    = number
      request_scheme_condition = map(list(string))

    }
  )

}
```

```
error: 
│ Error: Invalid default value for variable
│
│   on variables.tf line 92, in variable "delivery_rules":
│   92:   default = {
│   93:     name  = "test"
│   94:     order = 1
│   95:     request_scheme_condition = {
│   96:       match_value = "HTTP"
│   97:
│   98:       operator     = "Equal"
│   99:     }
│  100:   }
│
│ This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: attribute "request_scheme_condition": element "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `map(list(string))` you need object again:

```
variable "delivery_rules" {
   default = {
    name  = "test"
    order = 1
    request_scheme_condition = {
      match_value = ["HTTP"]
      operator = "Equal"
    }
  }

  type = object(
    {
      name                     = string
      order                    = number
      request_scheme_condition =  object({
          match_value = list(string)
          operator = string
        })
   })
}
```

Comment: while using the above code having issue. Could you please let me know the correction below code.

Comment: @hari989 the answer is correct and it works. If you have new issues, new question should be asked.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when I run your terraform code in my environment as shown:

[image]

**Cause is**: The map type in Terraform is *collection* and *all elements of a collection must always be of the same type.*

As your variable has several types for distinct fields, map(list(string)) will not work.

*I made a few changes to your script and was able to properly initialize the terraform with* `terraform init`.

```bash
variable "delivery_rules" {
   default = {
    name  = "test"
    order = 1
    request_scheme_condition = {
      match_value = "[HTTP]"
      operator = "Equal"
    }
  }
  type = object(
    {
      name                     = string
      order                    = number
      request_scheme_condition = object({
      match_value = string
      operator = string
    })
}
)
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Check to know the [Type constraints](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints) in Terraform.